# How to check if an HTML element has no class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to append a class to an anchor tag, which as no class. Also this anchor tag is inside many DIV elements and h4 tag
So h4 has a class say **abc** inside this h4 tag there is this anchor tag which doesn't have any class.This is what I tried but not working. I want to append a class to the anchor that doesn't have a class at present.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.abc a').hasClass(''){
   $(this).addClass('active');
 }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://www.bootply.com/119422)

Answer (score 11):

You could use:

```
$('.abc a').filter(':not([class])').addClass('active');
```

Comment: Ah I see. That's a much more sensible question.. +1

Comment: @oGeez I dont want to add on click or select of the anchor tag. I want it on document ready function. I know it is easy on using select.

Comment: @oGeez - now all the anchor tags are populated with the class **active** even if there is class defined for those anchors

Comment: @Mckenzi when you use `@oGeez` are you talking to me? Isn't it working? If no, please provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue

Comment: @A.Wolff my apologies I using a bootstrap css accordion which has first panel open and I want to add a minus sign to the panel that is open . So would like to have a plus minus thing.

Comment: @Mckenzi don't worry but anyway, using bootstrap or not doesn't change anything, this code provided in answer works so you are doing something wrong. So if your issue still persists, provide a jsfiddle

Comment: @A.Wolff I tried the JSfiddle but it doesn't work maybe there are files that need to be included but JSfiddle cant include

Comment: @A.Wolff Check this fiddle this is what I'm trying to do. The first panel should be highlighted if that panel is open. But as you can see from the fiddle it it highlighting all the Panel anchor tags Following is the link  http://www.bootply.com/119422

Comment: @A.Wolff Kindly check the link now.

Comment: @A.Wolff I have updated the question and added the fiddle link.

Comment: `if($('div').filter(':not(in)'))` What is `in`??? Why not using code i provided??? If you write wrong code for sure it won't work... Here you want: `if($('div').filter(':not(.in)'))` but then this is no more relevant to your opening post question which was: `I want to append a class to an anchor tag, which as no class`. Now rereading your question, i see you mean `which doesn't have a specific class`

Comment: @A.Wolff  `:not(in)` where `in` is the class name that bootstrap appends automatically when the panel is open. Also Yes i want to append a class to anchor if you see the Fiddle clearly I am appending a class to anchor tag.

Comment: @Mckenzi `:not(in)` should be `:not(.in)` see the dot?! Reread my previous comment, it was already there. I'm sorry but i cannot lose more time here because obviously you didn't make so much effort to resolve your issue... Have a good day...

Answer (score 4):

**Another Solution** :but @A. Wolff is better :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert($('.abc a').attr('class'))
    if(!$('.abc a').attr('class')){
     $('.abc a').addClass('active');
    }
    alert($('.abc a').attr('class'))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the length of the attribute class.
If it is 0, then you can add a class

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var classes = $('.abc a').attr('class');
    var cLength = classes.trim().length;
    if (clength==0) {
        $('.abc a').addClass('active');
    }
});
```